# Error: "failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open no such file or directory" using netcfg with wpa_supplicant

Tags: linux, arch-linux, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to set up netcfg so that I can finish installing Arch Linux (using the instructions from the [Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Wireless_2) and [netcfg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Netcfg)) and I passed over what was meant to be a short step. Open wifi-menu, select network, enter password. After multiple attempts, I decided to edit the profile manually, which yielded no improvement. Eventually I decided to use netfcg with the more familiar wpa_supplicant. My `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file is as follows:

```
network={
    ssid="my_ssid"
    #psk="my_wireless_passcode"
    psk="my_wireless_passcode_hex"
}
```

(Replacing generic names with my actual ssid and psk.)

And my `/etc/network.d/wpa_suppl` file reads:

```
CONNECTION='wireless'
DESCRIPTION='A wpa_supplicant configuration based wireless connection'
INTERFACE='wlan0'
SECURITY='wpa-config'
WPA_CONF='/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'
IP='dhcp'
```

My ssid is not hidden, wlan0 is the proper interface, and wpa_supplicant works fine on its own, but using `netcfg wpa_suppl`, it returns `failed to connect to wpa_supplicant - wpa_ctrl_open no such file or directory` about twelve times before finally telling me the authentication failed. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` incorrectly, due to an outdated wiki entry.

The configuration file for the wpa_supplicant package was moved to the sub-directory `/etc/wpa_supplicant/` a few months back.

Specify the file as `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` in your `/etc/network.d/wpa_suppl` file.

[Package](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/wpa_supplicant/) Contents:

```
etc/
etc/wpa_supplicant/
etc/dbus-1/
etc/dbus-1/system.d/
etc/dbus-1/system.d/wpa_supplicant.conf
etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
<snip>
```